# Why does “1|2” == 1 return true in PHP?

Tags: php

Why does this code return True instead of False?

```
"1|2" == 1
```

why doesn't it return False?

attention : 1|2 is string.

Comment: Are the backticks and the curly quotes part of this?

Comment: No Sorry for mistake!!

Comment: @Rizier123 Can you explain more,please?

Comment: === checks the type of variables you are comparing , '1' == 1(true), '1'===1(false)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string `"1|2"` is cast to an integer for the comparison with integer 1.

According to [PHP's type casting rules](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php), casting strings to integers takes all leading digits from the string up to the first non-digit (giving `1`, and ignoring `|2` because `|` is the first non-digit.

`1 == 1` is true

Comment: thank you for your answer! How to Fix it then to return false??

Comment: How to fix it? Rewrite your logic to be something that will logically return a false (e.g. `"1|2" == 2` or `1|2 == 1`)

Comment: No i do not mean that however i found it. i should cast 1 to string so it can be false!!

Comment: you can use strict comparsion `===` to avoid this

Answer (score 1):

When converted into a number `"1|2"` becomes `1` as the cast processes the string until the first non-numerical character. `1 == 1` so this is true. Strings are converted into numbers during `==` comparisons

> If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves
>   numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the
>   comparison performed numerically.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

If you want to fix it use the `===` operator which will also check types